# Issue regarding the Dockerfile creation

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am a newbie to docker and trying to understand how to create dockerfiles.
While attempting the same I created this sample file

```
FROM debian
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install apache2 -y
COPY ./index.html  /etc/www/html/
CMD service apache2 start && /bin/bash
```

The CMD part has always confused me and I am using the /bin/bash mostly because I read somewhere that we need to make sure that there is some running command in the Docker Image when we are bringing it up. I use this to run the image :-

```
docker run -t -p 5000:8080 --name myfinal 912ccd578eae
```

where I'm using the id of the image built. As you can see, I'm a novice and even the minutest of details would help.

Comment: Can you please clarify your doubt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) for apache2 should be

```
CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

That way, you don't have to use the "bash" trick to keep a foreground process running.
And any exit signal will impact correctly the apache2 process, not the bash one.

No need for [`ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) here:  Docker maintains a default entrypoint, `/bin/sh`.
So this (with `CMD`) is the same as:

```
 /bin/sh -c “apachectl -D FOREGROUND”
```

Comment: Good read on that topic: https://deninet.com/blog/1585/docker-scratch-part-3-entrypoints-and-ports

Comment: Minor note: When building the image, you can give it a name using the `-t` switch: e.g. `docker build -t my-image /path/to/Dockerfile`. You can then run it using: `docker run -t -p 5000:8080 --name myfinal my-image`